# Implementing a FIFO queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3.7 there are two options for an off-the-shelf FIFO queue object:

- `queue.Queue`
- `queue.SimpleQueue`

However, all that the docs say about a [`SimpleQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.SimpleQueue) is that:

> Constructor for an unbounded FIFO queue. Simple queues lack advanced functionality such as task tracking. *New in version 3.7.*

What would be a functional difference between then two?

Comment: in your link you can see what method has `Queue` and `SImpleQueue`. `SimpleQueue` doesn't have `join()`, `full()` and `task_done()` - so you can't block queue. And it doesn't have `maxsize` so you can't limit its size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally what [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#simplequeue-objects) you quoted tell you (the details can be gleaned by comparing the available methods):

1. `SimpleQueue` is always unbounded (`Queue` is optionally bounded); they removed the `full` method (because it can never be full)
2. `SimpleQueue` doesn't do task tracking, so it doesn't provide `task_done` (for consumers to indicate a task has been completed) or `join` (to allow a thread to block until all items `put` have had a matching `task_done` call)

This simplifies a lot of the code by dropping support for comparatively rare scenarios (I've almost never seen anyone use `task_done` or `join`, and when they do, it's often buggy, with exceptions potentially bypassing a `task_done`, making `join` block forever), improving performance a bit by side-effect.

Side-note: If you don't actually need the blocking features at all, you can skip the `queue` module and just [use `collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). It's still thread-safe and atomic for `append`s and `pop`s from either end, it just doesn't provide the ability to do a blocking `get` when the `deque` is empty, in exchange for being much lower overhead (implemented entirely in C, with no supplementary locking like `queue` classes).